# Unconditional branch not taken in AArch64 assembly

Tags: assembly, arm64

I'm just getting started in learning ARM assembly, and I have been attempting to put together a relatively simple program. When it's complete, the user will be able to enter a number (when prompted) to indicate the entry of the fibonacci sequence they want printed out. Currently, all I want it to do is print out the prompt, then print a hard-coded entry (in this case, I chose the 4th). I will figure out user input later.

However, I ran into a problem with branching (BL). I was able to branch to the external function `printf` to print the prompt, but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the second branch, to `fibo`. I assumed this because no matter what number I set *targ* to, it always prints out the initial value of `x3` which is 1 - **but** this isn't the case, it prints out 1 regardless of what x3's value is before entering the loop. The function 'fibo' is meant to store the current value of x3 in memory, along with the return address, check if the counter is less than or equal to the target #, and branch back to `loop` if it is. Then the loop modifies x3 and x4, for tail recursion - so x3 should definitely be changing. Can anyone shed some light on my issue?

```
  .text
  .global main
  .extern printf
main:
    mov x3,xzr  // set x3 and x4 -> (0, 1)
    mov x4,#1

    ldr x1,=targ  // set x1 to target (currently manually set)

    ldr x0, =prompt // print prompt
    bl printf

loop:
    mov x9, x3      // this chunk: (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (3, 5) ..
    mov x3, x4
    add x4, x9, x4

    bl fibo  // branch to fibo

    ldr x30,[sp,#8]  // load value and return address from stack
    ldr x3,[sp,#0]
    add x2, x3, x2   // x2 = x3 + x2
    add sp, sp, #16  

    mov x0,x2        // print out x2 by moving it to x0, then calling printf
    ldr x0,=stringpr
    bl printf 

    br x30

fibo:
    sub sp, sp, #16
    str x30,[sp,#8]
    str x3,[sp,#0]   // store current value of x3 in stack
    add x5,x5,#1
    cmp x5,x1    // test x5 (counter) is greater than target; if it is, ignore branch
    ble loop
    mov x2,#0
    add sp, sp, #16
    br x30
.data
    prompt:
        .asciz "Enter a number:\n"
    targ:
        .byte 4   // hard-coded value for 'targ'
    stringpr:
        .asciz "%d\n"
.end
```

**EDIT**

Registers and usages:

- x0 -> used when printing variables with printf
- x1 -> stores 'targ' variable, the target fibonacci entry
- x2 -> holds the return value for the fibonacci entry
- x3 -> holds the "tail" end of the tail recursion, for fibonacci seq.
- x4 -> holds the "head" end of tail recursion (e.g. '2' in [1,2], '8' in [5, 8])
- x5 -> holds the count, and is incremented each time `fibo` is called

Comment: Did you try single-stepping in a debugger to see the path of execution?  You don't store `x30` before the very first `bl printf` before the loop overwrites main's return address.

Comment: Note that the stack is supposed to be aligned to 16 bytes at all times, so pushes and pops should always use a pre/post index 16.  If you have two registers to push/pop, use `stp/ldp`.

Comment: You might like to look at compiler output to see what a standard function prologue/epilogue looks like.  As it stands you're handling the link register `x30` in a very haphazard fashion.

Comment: The control flow also looks weird.  `main` falls through into `loop`?  `loop` seems to be part of `fibo`, yet it's before the entry point of `fibo`?  It'd be helpful to have clear documentation of what each entry point is actually supposed to do, and what registers are used for inputs / outputs / clobbered.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I suppose the reason it looks so weird is because it's translated directly from code I wrote in pseudo-ARM (that I learned in class). I wanted to separate initializing code from code that was to be looped, so I just added `loop`. Loop is executed, which branches to `fibo`, which either returns to loop after checking that count (stored in x5) has not exceeded `targ` (which is stored in x2), or returns to the address in x30, set by `bl`. I have updated my post with register information.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I did step through it. And it shouldn't, that first print statement is only for the prompt, it isn't the print statement that returns the final result.

Comment: I don't care what it is supposed to print, any execution of `bl` trashes the previous contents of the link register x30, and if you haven't saved it away somewhere, you've lost your chance to successfully return to your caller.

Comment: Are you still claiming that execution fell through `bl fibo` and ran the `ldr x30,[sp,#8]` as the next instruction?  Or did `stepi` show you that it actually *is* taken, but you're returning to the wrong place some time later.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm struggling to see the relevance of the very first `bl` statement to the issue. If that return address isn't useful to the execution of the program (everything is supposed to happen in loop and fibo, including the final print), then what do I care if that particular address is overwritten by other `bl` calls?

Comment: How is `main` going to eventually return if you lose its return address?  You don't `bl exit` anywhere, so you need main's return address to return back to the CRT code that called `main`.

Comment: @PeterCordes But shouldn't I still see the proper output? Even if main doesn't return?

Comment: Sure, maybe, if your program does everything else right.  Use the debugger to single-step through it and see exactly what happens.  Your hypothesis about `bl fibo` not being taken can't be right, there's no way for that to happen.  Or maybe someone else will be interested in tracing through your code's weird logic of where and when you save / restore return addresses and finding the actual problem for you.

Comment: @PeterCordes Alright, thanks. And yes, I get it, it's weird, we've established this.

Comment: Ok, well as I see it, the question is still focused on the claim that a `bl` is not-taken.  The question title is about that, most of a big paragraph is about that.  We've established, I think, that isn't what's happening, so as I see it, the actual Stack Overflow question is solved, and you can get back to garden-variety debugging now that we've put to bed this worry that the CPU is being really weird and falling through a `bl`, mostly by reassuring you that's not possible.  This is why we use debuggers to single-step instead of just looking at printed output.

Comment: If you actually want someone else to debug it for you beyond that, you should rewrite most of the text of the question, and the title, showing actual output and what you see in registers while single-stepping through it, especially anything you didn't expect.